# Product showing up in Amazon MWS API but not Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-product-api

I'm building an integration for my warehouse and using Amazon's API's to get product information from UPC.  I've ran into a number of times where a result comes back accurately from the GetMatchingProduct on MWS API but not from the Product Advertising API.  Even Vice Versa has occurred.

Why might this be?  Is there a reason I should just use one or the other?

Example: UPC - 363824072463
MWS brings back ASIN - B0057UUHGU which is the relevant one that also comes back when you just search Amazon.  However the Product Advertising API does not return this in its list of results at all.

Answer (score 0):

We have found that often times new, or recently changed items take a little while to correctly populate in the Product Advertising API.

Also, for what you say your purposes are, I would be cautious relying on the Product Advertising API. It is a sales tool, so sometimes when given an out-of-stock item, for instance, it will return results of a different item (maybe similar, maybe was variated with it, etc) as the purpose of that API is to drive sales to Amazon.

Comment: I've seen that too, but these are for older items that seem to actually be prime available and have decent sales.  Their doesn't seem to be a rhyme or reason (like many things Amazon).

Comment: Also i do use the boto/MWS a lot as well, but i need to support an initial search that allows for keyword/upc/ASIN/EAN/etc... to just display options for the user to dive into.  Once I have an ASIN, it's all MWS API.